# IntelliJ Idea using wrong git

Tags: git, macos, intellij-idea

I'm unable to get git working with IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1 (Ultimate Edition)
MacOS Monterey, 12.5, Chip: Apple M1 Pro

Path to git executable: /usr/local/bin/git

And IntelliJ Idea gives me error message:
`Failed to start Git process: Cannot run program "/usr/local/bin/git" (in directory "."): error=86, Bad CPU type in executable`

But my git installation is OK

> % git --version
> git version 2.37.1 (Apple Git-137.1)

> % which git
> /usr/local/bin/git

Interesting is, that I'll bet similar error in bash

> % bash
> $ git --version
> bash: /usr/local/bin/git: Bad CPU type in executable

It looks like I have two different versions of git installed, and Idea wants to use the bad one. But it is the same git, look:

> $ which git
> /usr/local/bin/git

Could someone explant pls what is going on?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT211861

Comment: ended up with the same mess after uninstalling Rosetta because it was causing too many architecture clashes

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your git is built for Intel CPU.

You can first remove the current git files or install Rosetta 2 (Binary translator), in terminal `/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license` and reboot your Mac.

And you can also remove the current git files and install an M1 version git in one of the following ways:

#### Xcode Command Line Tools(The recommended way)

Bring up a terminal and input this command:

`xcode-select --install`

Please read this article for more information:

https://mac.install.guide/commandlinetools/4.html

#### Homebrew

Install [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) if you don't already have it, then:

`$ brew install git`

#### MacPorts

Install [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) if you don't already have it, then:
`$ sudo port install git`

Answer (score 2):

You’re trying to run a program for the wrong architecture, which in this case is Git. You have to use a version compiled for ARM64 architecture.

I don't know how you installed your Git, if you migrated from an Intel Mac to Apple Silicon, or if the IntelliJ installation installed the wrong Git version.

1. Install Rosetta 2 (Binary translator), in terminal `/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license`

After reboot, check if it works. If not...

2. Uninstall all Git versions from your machine and install this homebrew version: [Git OSX](https://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/)

Answer (score 0):

you already have git installed as part of Xcode installation. Simply remove the other git by firing the uninstall.sh from /usr/local/git . You need to be an admin for this.